# how can I extract specific row which contain specific keyword from my json dataset using pandas in python?

Tags: python, json, pandas

sorry that might be very simple question but I am new to python/json and everything. I am trying to filter my twitter json data set based on user_location/country_code/gb. but I have no idea how to do this. I have tried several ways but still no chance. I have attached my data set and some codes I have used here. I would appreciate any help.

here is what I did to get the best result however I do not know how to tell it to go for whole data set and print out the result of tweet_id:

```
import json

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json('example.json', lines=True)
if df['user_location'][4]['country_code'] == 'th':
  print (df.tweet_id[4])

else: 
  print('false')
```

this code show me the tweet_id : `1223489829817577472`
however, I couldn't extend it to the whole data set.

I have tried theis code as well, still no chance:

```
dataset = df[df['user_location'].isin([ "gb" ])].copy()

print (dataset)
```

[that is what my data set looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0AbW.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would break the `user_location` column into multiple columns using the following

```
df = pd.concat([df, df.pop('user_location').apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
```

Running this should give you a column each for the keys contained within the `user_location` json. Then it should be easy to print out tweet_ids based on country_code using:

```
df[df['country_code']=='th']['tweet_id']
```

#### An explanation of what is actually happening here:

- `df.pop('user_location')` removes the 'user_location' column from df and returns it at the same time
- With the returned column, we use the `.apply` method to apply a function to the column
- `pd.Series` converts the JSON data/dictionary into a DataFrame
- `pd.concat` concatenates the original df (now without the 'user_location' column) with the new columns created from the 'user_location' data

Comment: yes, of course, I did it now. But I have another question if you do not mind answering me. this query bring back tweet_id only. how can bring back all the other column if the country_code is 'th' for example

Comment: Sure, just remove [tweet_id] from the last line so it's just `df[df['country_code']=='th']`. This will return all columns.